# Amazon AWS Ubuntu php5 fpm php.ini file

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I've installed an ubuntu machine on AWS, I installed php-fpm, and then I do phpinfo and get

> Loaded Configuration File /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

But when I make changes to the `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` file  and restart php-fpm server, nothing happens, it is not loaded.

What could be the issue?

Is there a way to explicitly define what `php.ini` I want to use?

Comment: Maybe a different PHP version is installed and being used by default - did you uninstall all PHP versions first? Try `php -v` to see the version, or `php -i` command to see more information

Comment: There are no other versions installed (afaic), is there a way to explicitly define what php.ini I want to use?